# Sampling a continuous function to create sequence of discrete values

Tags: difference-equations

My question is straightforward: How do I convert a continuous function into a discrete-valued function?

The function I want to convert is the JacobiAmplitude function:

```
ϕ[t_] = With[{k = 1.01}, JacobiAmplitude[k t, k^-3]]; 

Plot[ϕ[t], {t, 0, 50}]
```

I am using `RSolve` to solve a second-order difference equation and want to add a discrete-time version of the `JacobiAmplitude` function to the model as a forcing term.

I'd like to put a discrete-time `JacobiAmplitude` function, ϕ[n], into the following difference equation:

```
RSolve[
 {y[n + 2] - y[n + 1] + 0.99*y[n] == ϕ[n], {y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1, ϕ[0] == 0}}, 
 y[n], n
];

ListPlot[
  Transpose@Table[{y[n]} /. First[%],
  {n, 0, 350}], 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All
]
```

I'd immensely appreciate any assistance.

Comment: i dont think you even need `RSolve` here, just do `y[n_]:=  y[n-1] - 0.99*y[n-2] +ϕ[n-2]`. No need for phi to be discrete.

Comment: If you need the discrete function because your evaluation is too slow, then you could try memoization. That is, `y[n_] := y[n] = y[n - 1] - 0.99*y[n - 2] + ϕ[n - 2]` (Similar to @george2079 's solution, but with an extra `y[n] =`; this will prevent redundant evaluations).

Answer (score 1):

```
y[n_] := Evaluate[(y[n] /. 
     RSolve[{y[n + 2] - y[n + 1] + 0.99*y[n] == ϕ[n], {y[0] == 0,
         y[1] == 1}}, y[n], n])[[1]]];
```

`RSolve` does not automatically `Set` the definition of `y`, so you need to assign it manually. Also, the condition `ϕ[0] == 0` in your `RSolve` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: its good to see how this is done, but note in this case using the `RSolve` result is much slower than directly crunching out the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple approach to your problem.

```
ϕ[t_] := With[{k = 1.01}, JacobiAmplitude[k t, k^-3]]

y[0] = 0; y[1] = 1;
y[n_] := y[n] = y[n - 1] - 0.99*y[n - 2] + ϕ[n - 2]

DiscretePlot[y[n], {n, 0, 350}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

You might want to look this [this documentation article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) for more information.